# How to have Menus common to all page in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm learning Swift and I wanted to make a Menu that is common to all pages. How do I do it? Currently, I'm manually adding a 'menu button' on each page and add an action to toggle the menu. By the way I'm using this library called **ENSideMenu**. The menu looks like this.[image]

Comment: Tabbar ? Toolbar ? Floating button (similar to Material Design) ? Container ViewControllers ? There are several approaches.

Comment: @nathan I don't know what is it called since I'm still new, but I posted a sample shot

Comment: Add the menu on a controller and on click of a button, add the view on the controller where you want to present.

Comment: Simply create a custom `UINavigationController` that have the button and assign the class to all navigation controller, the button will appear everywhere

Comment: @KaelJasper, Please check, i have added answer, if you satisfied then up vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create one common class for that, and just call that function. Here is the example.

Call below function in your view did load method

```
CommonSingleton.sharedInstance.setNavigationItem(itemTitleName: "Menu", navigationItem: self.navigationItem, actionBtn: #selector(self.sideMenuBtnPressed), target: self)
```

Create one swift file, named **CommonSingleton**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

private let sharedToken = CommonSingleton()

class CommonSingleton {

    class var sharedInstance: CommonSingleton {
        return sharedToken
    }

    func setNavigationItem(itemTitleName: String, navigationItem:UINavigationItem, actionBtn:Selector,target:Any ){
        if(itemTitleName=="Refresh"){
//            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: target, action: actionBtn)
            let btnCreateBid: UIButton = UIButton()
            let image  = UIImage(named: "navRefresh")
            btnCreateBid.setImage(image, for: .normal)
            btnCreateBid.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (image?.size.width)!, height: (image?.size.height)!)
            btnCreateBid.addTarget(target, action: actionBtn, for: .touchUpInside)
            btnCreateBid.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
            btnCreateBid.clipsToBounds = true
            let rightItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
            rightItem.customView = btnCreateBid
            rightItem.customView?.layer.cornerRadius=5.0
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem
        }
        else if(itemTitleName=="Done"){
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: target, action: actionBtn)
        }
        else if (itemTitleName=="Back") {
            let btnCreateBid: UIButton = UIButton()
            let image  = UIImage(named: "icons_Back")
            btnCreateBid.setImage(image, for: .normal)
            btnCreateBid.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (image?.size.width)!, height: (image?.size.height)!)
            btnCreateBid.addTarget(target, action: actionBtn, for: .touchUpInside)
            btnCreateBid.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
            btnCreateBid.clipsToBounds = true
            let rightItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
            rightItem.customView = btnCreateBid
            rightItem.customView?.layer.cornerRadius=5.0
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = rightItem
        }
        else if(itemTitleName=="Menu"){
            let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: .plain, target: target, action: actionBtn)
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
        }
        else if(itemTitleName=="CreateBid"){
            let btnCreateBid: UIButton = UIButton()
            btnCreateBid.setImage(UIImage(named: "create_bid"), for: .normal)
            btnCreateBid.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
            btnCreateBid.addTarget(target, action: actionBtn, for: .touchUpInside)
            btnCreateBid.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
            btnCreateBid.clipsToBounds = true
            let rightItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
            rightItem.customView = btnCreateBid
            rightItem.customView?.layer.cornerRadius=5.0
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem
        }
        else if(itemTitleName=="MoreOption"){
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_more_vert_"), style: .plain, target: target, action: actionBtn)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply done by creating a superview controller and on its viewdidload create a button and assign an action to it.

I have created a menu slider in swift 3.0 [here](https://github.com/Nexengineer/NMSliderMenu)

Use it as a reference if you want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The library currently doesn't support 2 menus in the same page